# SQL - Revert column concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE my_wallet_transactions 
  SET funds_source = funds_source || CHR(10) || CHR(10) || income_source;
```

This is my original script to merge data from one column to another.

Now my line of work requires writing a backout script for every script. So essentially I want to write scripts to revert the above script without loosing any data in both columns. Can someone help identify some strategies to make it work? I copied the original values of `funds_source` in another column `funds_source_bkp` but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do regular transactions and backups not accomplish this? Well if there are no line breaks in the original elements then you could revert by splitting that way. But fundamentally I think this is a flawed mandate and where it's possible it will require specific knowledge of the data involved. As it appears here that you're only modifying one column you should be able to use the contents of the `income_source` to undo the operation.

Comment: What's `CHR(10)`? A function to get 10 blanks or something? Or Line-feed?

Comment: If you have not modified any value in  income_source column, just take a substring of funds_source from the 1st char to `length(funds_source)-length(income_source)-2`.

Comment: @jarlh Line-feed. It's a function to convert a decimal value to a char, reverse of `ascii`. I just wonder why it's 0A0A instead of 0D0A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your life a whole lot easier by saving `funds_source_bkpbut`, and can just update the column back to it. For safety's sake, you probably would also like to check that it's not `null`, in order to not mess up new rows inserted after this change was made

```sql
UPDATE my_wallet_transactions 
SET    funds_source = funds_source_bkpbut
WHERE  funds_source_bkpbut IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution was right in front of me. And good point on checking for NULL.